# Third column in a 3 column layout not displaying correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to make 3 column layout.

column 1: fixed `(.stepnumber)`

column 2: fluid `(.instruction)`

column 3: fixed `(.stepbutton)`

Here is my CSS

```
.container
{
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.stepnumber
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: center;

}
.instruction
{
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;

}
.stepbutton
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

The third column does not float to right of fluid column, it drops down to a new line and the -200px offset moves it kind of off the page.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `float`, use CSS `table` or `flex` instead can make it easier.

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.left {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
}
.middle {
    background: green;
}
.right {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="middle">2</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```